# What is MemCache and how does it work internally?

Tags: architecture, memcached, system-design

I am learning system design principals and a lot of HLD and LLDs. In one of the designs, it was mentioned that FB is using MemCache for the news feed generation, etc. Can someone please help me or give any resources link to understand it correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Memcache is an in-memory key-value store. As it is purely in-memory it is very fast. It has no persistence though and if it restarts all data will be lost. Most often it is used to store information that was expensive to generate (eg: complex SQL query, or a dynamic web page) so that if requested again the data can be retrieved much quicker. In this sense it is a universal cache. Furthermore, it is scalable horizontally by using multiple memcache servers in parallel.

I suggest that you take a look at https://memcached.org/. The website explains things in more detail than I and you can download the source code it that interests you.

Answer (score 1):

Before you understand what Memcached is, it is important to understand caching. Instead of writing about it myself, I'm quoting the following text from https://aws.amazon.com/caching/

> **What is Caching?** In computing, a cache is a high-speed data storage layer which stores a subset of data, typically transient in
> nature, so that future requests for that data are served up faster
> than is possible by accessing the data’s primary storage location.
> Caching allows you to efficiently reuse previously retrieved or
> computed data.
>
> **How does Caching work?** The data in a cache is generally stored in fast access hardware such as RAM (Random-access memory) and may also
> be used in correlation with a software component. A cache's primary
> purpose is to increase data retrieval performance by reducing the need
> to access the underlying slower storage layer.
>
> Trading off capacity for speed, a cache typically stores a subset of
> data transiently, in contrast to databases whose data is usually
> complete and durable.

e.g. think of an eCommerce application which has a customer-facing UI using which a lot of customers browse products and do some transactions. Since the products are limited, customers visit the same products again and again. If for each of these visits, data is fetched from the database, the performance will be very bad. In order to alleviate the load from the database, a cache is used to store the requested data so that when a user requests for some information, the application will first look into the cache and if it is found there, the application won't go to the database for it; rather, it will fetch the data from the cache and serve it. If the data is not found in the cache, the application will try to fetch the same from the database and depending on the configuration, the data may also be written to the cache so that the next request of the same data can be served from the cache itself rather than going to the database. The application makes sure to invalidate the cache and refresh the data in the cache when it changes in the database.

As you can find from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memcached, Memcached is a general-purpose distributed memory caching system which was developed in 2003 and quickly found widespread use as a means to reduce the load on databases. It is a network-aware cache that store key-value data in RAM. Thus, it is not persistent storage and if the machine on which it runs crashes, the data is lost.

You can learn more about it by visiting the links which I mentioned above. You can also visit https://memcached.org/ for any additional information you may need.